# How can I access a variable in an JButton ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Hopefully this isn't to much of a mess, i'm new to java. And I can't figure out how to access the "iDaysAlive" variable outside of the ActionListener.

```
    JButton jButton_Calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    jButton_Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

            int iDayBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBDay.getText());
            int iMonthBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBMonth.getText());
            int iYearBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBYear.getText());

            int iDayCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdDay.getText());
            int iMonthCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdMonth.getText());
            int iYearCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdYear.getText());

            double iDaysAlive;

            Calendar caBirthDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearBirth, iMonthBirth - 1, iDayBirth);
            Calendar caCurrentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearCurrent, iMonthCurrent - 1, iDayCurrent);

            iDaysAlive = caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis();
            iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1; //this variable
        }
    });

    jButton_Calculate.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 15));
    jButton_Calculate.setBounds(180, 205, 103, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jButton_Calculate);

    JLabel lblDaysAlive = new JLabel("Days Alive: " + iDaysAlive);

    //iDaysAlive cannot be resolved to a variable

    lblDaysAlive.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblDaysAlive.setBounds(135, 257, 147, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblDaysAlive);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't, the variable iDaysAlive is only visible in the scope of the actionPerformed method.

even if you would add it as field of the class, you can't access it because of the anonimyous construction of the ActionListener.

Implement a class implementing ActionListener like

```
class MyCoolActionListener implements ActionListener
{
double iDaysAlive;
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

        int iDayBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBDay.getText());
        int iMonthBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBMonth.getText());
        int iYearBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBYear.getText());

        int iDayCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdDay.getText());
        int iMonthCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdMonth.getText());
        int iYearCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdYear.getText());

        double iDaysAlive;

        Calendar caBirthDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearBirth, iMonthBirth - 1, iDayBirth);
        Calendar caCurrentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearCurrent, iMonthCurrent - 1, iDayCurrent);

        iDaysAlive = caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis();
        iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1; //this variable
    }
public double getIDaysAlive()
{
return iDaysAlive;
}
}
```

and add iDaysAlive as field to it. write getter and setter methods and use it like

```
MyCoolActionListener al = new MyCoolActionListener()
jButton_Calculate.addActionListener(al);
al.getIDaysAlive();
```

edit: or well, much easier: define the variable you need access to outside of the actionListener

Comment: what does MyCoolActionLIstener represent here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to acces a variable outside of a function you have to declare the variable outside the function. Just write `double iDaysAlive;` before your function

```
double iDaysAlive; // Declare outside
JButton jButton_Calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
jButton_Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

        int iDayBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBDay.getText());
        int iMonthBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBMonth.getText());
        int iYearBirth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_DoBYear.getText());

        int iDayCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdDay.getText());
        int iMonthCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdMonth.getText());
        int iYearCurrent = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_CdYear.getText());


        Calendar caBirthDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearBirth, iMonthBirth - 1, iDayBirth);
        Calendar caCurrentDate = new GregorianCalendar(iYearCurrent, iMonthCurrent - 1, iDayCurrent);

        iDaysAlive = caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis();
        iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1; //this variable
    }
});

jButton_Calculate.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 15));
jButton_Calculate.setBounds(180, 205, 103, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(jButton_Calculate);

JLabel lblDaysAlive = new JLabel("Days Alive: " + iDaysAlive);

//you have now acces to the variable iDaysAlive

lblDaysAlive.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
lblDaysAlive.setBounds(135, 257, 147, 21);
frame.getContentPane().add(lblDaysAlive);
```

Comment: I've tried this but once i move it outside i get an error here:

iDaysAlive = caCurrentDate.getTimeInMillis() - caBirthDate.getTimeInMillis();
       iDaysAlive = iDaysAlive / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1;

// Cannot refer to a non-final variable iDaysAlive inside an inner class defined in a different method


Do you know why this is?

Comment: now it says "illegal modifier for parameter iDaysAlive; only final is permitted"

Comment: where do you write this code? in a function or in main?

Comment: in a function inside the main, should i have included this in the post?

Comment: yes... because every variable in the main has to be static... put this into a new function

Answer (score 1):

To access the variable outside of the anonymous class it has to be declared outside and it has to be `final`.

In your case this will not work, because if you make the double final you cannot change it. So you can either use a concrete class instead of the anonymous one to store the result in an attribute to access it later. Alternatively you could use a helper class for the result which can be declared final and holds an attribute to be changed from the anonymous action listener. Or you could make it simply an attribute of the enclosing class.

Comment: true that. or you could declare it as field of the class, then you're allowed to modify it

Answer (score 1):

```
double iDaysAlive;
```

This should be declared outside of the function, and more preferably at the top of the class. In fact, you should read about global vs local variables as this will help you a lot. For the mean time, place

```
double iDaysAlive = 0.0;
```

at the beginning of the class and it should be fine.